# How do I associate my user's spending with their profile in firebase?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently working on a Money Tracking app and I want to associate each user's spending activity with their profile, i.e. how do I store their expenses according to date and associate it with their profile? I am using Firebase Realtime Database. Currently, my user tree looks something like this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its pretty simple. All you can do is Create a separate node **spending** and save your data using Firebase User Id as parent Node and then date as child node with spending record of that current date so , later you can few record for each separate date as well.
and for clean code you can use [MyFirebase Helper Classes Kotlin](https://github.com/AtifAbbAsi19/Clean-architecture-android/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/droid/clean_architecture_android_tutorial/network/firebase) & [MyFirebase Helper Class java](https://github.com/AtifAbbAsi19/Firebase-Helper/blob/master/app/src/main/java/inc/droidflick/firebasetutorial/firebasenetwork/FireBaseHelper.java)

Comment: and how do I save it for different years? I assume by creating another node inside spending node?

Comment: Spending - Year - UserId - date with record for each day , try this.@PrateekSharma

Comment: Did that, but my reputation is less than 15. So, it won't be visible.